# record is not added to the table

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to save a new record to the table - Body.
I use Spring Boot and HTML.
so it looks in HTML:

```
<select id="bodiesList" multiple="multiple" class="selector">
    <option th:each="b : ${bodies}"
    th:value="${b.id}"
    th:text="${b.name}"></option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/general")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("orderServiceImpl")
    private OrderService orderService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public String get(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("orders", orderService.getOrders());

        return "general/index";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/showFormForAdd")
    public String add(Model theModel) {
        Orders orders = new Orders();

        List<Body> body = orderService.getBody();

        theModel.addAttribute("bodies", body);
        theModel.addAttribute("order", orders);

        return "general/create-orders";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/saveOrders")
    public String addOrders(@ModelAttribute("order") Orders orders, @RequestParam("picture") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        orders = orderService.uploadOrders(orders, file);
        orderService.save(orders);

        return "redirect:/general/list";
    }

}
```

but not in the database not in my column nothing is saved.

[image]

what needs to be fixed in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **th:field** to send the values from your html page to your controller. try something like this -

```
 <select th:field="*{body}" id="bodiesList" multiple="multiple" class="selector">
                    <option th:each="b : ${bodies}"
                            th:value="${b.id}"
                            th:text="${b.name}"></option>
                </select>
```

And then capture this information on your controller after form submit (same as your're capturing the `orders` on your `saveOrder` controller.

Read more about **th:field** in thymelead official documentation here - https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But now my column Body in the table is not displaying correctly. Like on a picture: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkeBQ.jpg) How can this be fixed?

Comment: What I understand from the picture is that you only need the value of **name** from the **body**, so simply extract the value of **name** field from **body** object before saving in the database, something like this -  body.getName(); and then save it